# Can't print items of the observables after grouped

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-scala, reactivex

Can't understand why the following [rxscala](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala) code is not working as expected:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

object MyTest extends App {

  case class ProjectEvent(projectName: String, description: String)

  val projectEvents: Observable[ProjectEvent] = Observable.just(
    ProjectEvent("aaa", "d1"),
    ProjectEvent("bbb", "d2"),
    ProjectEvent("aaa", "d3")
  )

  lazy val grouped = projectEvents.groupBy(_.projectName).map { case (projectName, eventsOfThisProject) =>
    println("projectName: " + projectName)
    eventsOfThisProject.foreach(x => "######### event in project " + projectName + ": " + x)
    (projectName, eventsOfThisProject)
  }

  grouped.foreach(println)
}
```

I grouped the `projectEvents` by the `projectName` and want to print the items of each project. But when I run this code, it only prints:

```
projectName: aaa
(aaa,rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions$$anon$2@49de17f4)
projectName: bbb
(bbb,rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions$$anon$2@52f6438d)
```

There is no `######### event in project` printed.

I can't understand why, is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `println` in this line:

```
eventsOfThisProject.foreach(x => "######### event in project " + projectName + ": " + x)
```

The function in `foreach` just converts `x` to a `String` but doesn't print it.